# Underdetermined System Cost

Tags: linear-algebra

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3\\ 
2 & 6
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
10\\ 
20
\end{bmatrix}$

Is an underdetermined system.

How do I find the shortest vector in S?

Let $\left \| v \right \|$ be the cost of the solution vector $v$, what is the solution that has the lowest cost?

Not really sure how to approach the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You know that:
$$x=10-3y$$
and you want to minimize $||v||$ with respect to $y$:
$$||v||=\sqrt{(10-3y)^2+y^2}=\sqrt{100-60y+10y^2}$$

You can show this expression is minimized at $y=3$, and therefore at $x=1$.

Comment: What is the solution space so I can step through your process?

Comment: @Matt - if that wasn't clear, the solution space is simply $(10-3y,y)$

Comment: Okay, so $||v||$ is the lowest cost solution, but then how would I calculate the shortest vector? Still a bit confused on your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt - the shortest vector is $(x,y)=(1,3)$.

Comment: @Matt - if you like answers on this site, please feel free to accept and upvote them if you find the answer helpful.